# Update an existing DE using Interactive Email Form

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, interactive-email

I hope you can help with this simple question.

I'm collecting "Mobile number" and "radio button selection" from this Interactive email Form. Now these elements are going into an existing DE, but this DE is also shared with a Smart capture page. I would like to "append" mobile number and radio button selection from all those customers with the same email.
At the moment I have duplication of rows with customers having the same email address.
I'm sure I have to use the hidden fields in the content studio, in order to update the DE but not sure how to do it. Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! Is there a primary key set for the data extension you're trying to write data to?

Comment: Hello Antonio, thanks for the help! Yeah, there is a primary key set in my data extension (email). I'm not sure how I should "trigger" data extension update... Injecting AMP script? Automation? Not sure how to proceed, any suggestion is more than welcome! THanks!

Comment: Hi Katia, no problem! If you have a primary key defined in your data extension (in this case, email address), the expected behaviour is that the system will attempt to update and overwrite the existing row if an email address already exists: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_interactive_email_form_faq.htm&type=5. Is the email address being passed in your form along with the mobile number and radio button selection?

Comment: Wow Antonio!!! is working now!! THanks so much!!! you made my day! All the best!!!!!